# How to avoid hard coding access key and security key values aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sts, access-keys

In my js file, I am accessing my AWS sns, but the main issue is that currently, I am hard coding my IAM access and security keys... Is there a way to avoid doing this by using a temporary key or hiding my keys? I have posted a snippet on how I am updating the config below.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({

  region: < 'My Hard coded region' >,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: < 'My Hard coded Access Key' >,
    secretAccessKey: <'My Hard Coded Security Key'>
     }
});
...
```

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to comment without knowing more about your code.

The react native is a mobile app. You will need a service to authenticate your mobile app users against the service. One such service is amazon Cognito.

#### Userpool

Amazon Cognito has a concept called `user pool`. The user pool is where the users are stored.

When you authenticate a user against a user pool, you will get a authorised token in return. Your app can store this token and send it to your backend services. The backend services can validate the token to confirm the identity of the user.

#### Identity pool

The identity pool is a concept where temporary AWS credentials are issued in exchange for an authorised token. This is the temporary AWS credentials, using which you can call aws services directly from the mobile app.

Hope this helps.

here is an article for you to read - https://pusher.com/tutorials/serverless-react-native-aws-amplify

Comment: I haven't used react native or mobile app development, But i thought this might give you some context.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! So I have userpool set up, after the user has logged into my app I'm wondering how to pass temporary credentials. I can see the token that the user is issued by running 'console.log(Auth)'. With the token the user is assigned, would it work to say 'credentials: {Auth.user.jwtToken}' instead of placing the access key and security key of my IAM user?

Comment: sorry i don't follow you. are you getting `access key` and `security key` or not

Answer (score 1):

I came across this stackoverflow while googling how to solve this problem. Here's the approach I ended up using to solve this problem in case this helps anyone else. It will expand on the identity pool answer provided earlier.

My setup was this:
Static website hosted on s3, so no way to make AJAX calls back to the server itself to bypass hardcoding credentials.

The solution I ended up using was Cognito identity pools as mentioned. The setup involved creating an identity provider in IAM. We were using an company internal OpenID identity provider. Then the next step was to create an identity pool in cognito that pointed to that identity provider. Next was to provision an IAM role for signed in users of that identity pool to give them access to whatever resources you are trying to secure.

On the s3 website, we had already integrated with the internal OpenID identity provider, so it was just a matter of extracting the token and passing it to Cognito.

The program flow is as follows:

1. User logs in to open ID internal system.
2. This system returns a token
3. Code extracts token and then creates a Cognito Identity Credentials
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html

The below is a code snippet copy pasted from the docs linked above. Note that the Logins object is where we will pass the token. The key will be the "provider" field value configured in IAM.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

// Configure the credentials provider to use your identity pool
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: { // optional tokens, used for authenticated login
        'graph.facebook.com': 'FBTOKEN',
        'www.amazon.com': 'AMAZONTOKEN',
        'accounts.google.com': 'GOOGLETOKEN',
        'appleid.apple.com': 'APPLETOKEN'
    }
});

// Make the call to obtain credentials
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

});
```

4. The call to cognito will return temporary credentials including a session token, which you can now pass to your other aws clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are much more secure ways to handle credentials. Hard coding them is the least secure.

> While it is possible to do so, we do not recommend hard-coding your AWS credentials in your application. Hard-coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Also see From Best Practices for Managing AWS Access Keys:

> Don't embed access keys directly into code. The AWS SDKs and the AWS Command Line Tools allow you to put access keys in known locations so that you do not have to keep them in code.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html

The most secure method  is to load the credentials from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for Amazon EC2.

Each SDK has a way to do this. Check your SDK documentation for loading credentials from IAM.

Here is a good overview for credentials best practices, with examples in Java:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/credentials-best-practices/